How to run 2 functions (calling themselves at specific frequencies and sharing variables) in parallell
I would like to run 2 functions, as such each function is calling itself:

f1 is calling itself every second to 1) get back z 2) update y(x, z).
f2 is calling itself every 5 minutes to 1) publish y 2) update x.

I want f2 to be called precisely every 5 minutes without being delayed by the run of f1 and I expect the current execution of f1 to wait before launching its next occurrence if f2 has been called (in order to get back the updated value of x).
I am currently using asyncio but the run of f2 is always delayed waiting for the current occurrence of f1 to be done. What would you suggest to do that in the best way ?
Thanks for your precious help
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
 
 
class Record(object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        asyncio_loop
    ):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.asyncio_loop = asyncio_loop
 
    def c(self, z):
        # Compute self.y given z and self.x (y is a record timestamped at x)
        return self.y
 
    def c2(self):
        # We publish self.y
        return 0
   
    def run(self):
        self.x = datetime.now() + (datetime.min - datetime.now()) % timedelta(minutes=5)
        delay_f2 = (self.x - datetime.now()).total_seconds()
        # We start processing y asap using function f1
        self.asyncio_loop.call_later(0, self.f1)
        # We start publishing (through function f2) y at the nearest rounded 5 minutes
        self.asyncio_loop.call_later(delay_f2, self.f2)
        self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
 
    def f1(self):
        # We get back z and compute y, every 1 second.
        z = ---
        self.y = self.c(z)
        self.asyncio_loop.call_later(1, self.f1)
 
    def f2(self):
        # We publish the y that has been computed over the past 'delay_f2' seconds, as soon as we have reached the nearest 5 minutes
        c2()
        # Once y published, we update x to jump to the nearest 5 minutes and to be able to publish the y that will be updated over the 5 upcoming minutes
        self.x = self.x + timedelta(minutes=5)
        delay_f2 = (self.x - dt_now).total_seconds()
        self.asyncio_loop.call_later(delay_f2, self.f2)


Please post a [mre]. I should be able to copy and paste your code and run it without any additions, deletions or modifications.

What you say you want is actually impossible.  Even specialized microcontrollers, designed for real-time control, cannot "precisely" execute a function with exact periodicity.  On a modern operating system, your program must share the CPU with other programs and processes, which can pre-empt you in a way that isn't under your control.  So you have to settle for something that only approximates what you want.  Asyncio isn't magic in any case.  You might want to look into multiprocessing, which at least allows your two functions to run on separate CPU cores, probably the best you can do.
